# Glassfish: EJB Timer Service not available when deploying application because of corrupt derby database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, derby

When deploying an application to Glassfish 3, an error is thrown that the EJB timer service is not available. The root cause is

```
ERROR XSLAO: Recovery failed unexpected problem log record is Not first but transaction is not in transaction table 
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
```

I have found some related discussions to this error with respect to other products. However, is there a standard way to clean up the Derby database used for timers in Glassfish?

UPDATE: The error has been fixed by cleaning up the `log` directory of the database following [these instructions](http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/corrupt-database-td108165.html). However, this is only a quick and dirty hack. Any other workarounds?

Comment: Can you reproduce this recovery failure from a fresh database? If so, please try to report it to the Derby community so they can fix it, as that's not a failure I've seen before.

Comment: @BryanPendleton The error happens at the customer site. We probably can not reproduce it. Would it be helpful to attach the files found in the log subdirectory?